# How to increase mouse 'activation' area

Tags: windows, mouseevent, mouse

Is it possible to somehow increase area on which mouse 'discovers' things on screen?
I don't mean increase cursor size because even if the cursor is HUGE then you need to point exactly with top of an arrow on object to select it.
I would like to be able to select things even if I'm not pointing on them exactly with top of an arrow but they are close enough.
Is it possible to change that 'settings' somewhere in Windows?

Comment: There is an accessibility setting that slows the mouse down over buttons in a dialog, that's probably the closest thing to what you're asking for.